# How to create a grid layout like this?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate grid something like this. But, I am struck here. 
Kindly let me know what should I do?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSyXo.jpg

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When posting, it's a good idea to follow some of the norms of the community, as they will help you get better answers. Take a look at this article on "How do I ask a good question?" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which has some useful details about creating a "Minimal, Reproducible Example."

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow, generally it's good to show what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Here's a starting point:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

.block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. So, how should I make this mobile responsive. All the blocks has to fill the entire width of the screen and should be stacked one by one. Thank you. I tried to use order property & width to 100% but it isn't seems to be working for me.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use flexbox and give it 1 column and 1 row, and after separate them using margin.
U need to also make one div for two rectangles which will be located in this columns and another div for row one's

```
  <div class="cointainer">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="rectangle1"> </div>
        <div class="rectangle2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="rectangle3"></div>

        <div class="rectangle4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```